# Jqgrid max limit add

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid jqGrid 4.14.2-pre

I want to set the limit for adding rows

RowNum: 50 Does not help as much as I use Page numbers

How can I set a limit of 5,000 entries

If the user adds 5001 then nothing will be added

Comment: You should add the code, which shows how the user adds the data to the grid. You can disable the feature (for example disable or hide the "Add" button) after arriving the limit (5,000 entries).

Comment: If I disable the button
$('#grid_iladd').hide();
The user can remove the value of none the html code and the button will appear again

Comment: I don't understand which scenario you has. If you want that the user not place *accidentally* the entry which will not be processed then hiding/disabling the button would be the best way. You have to control all really important limitation of your application **on the server side**. Thus it the user would post 5001-th entry then he/she should get the error message, generated by the server, and no entry should be added. Such logic has no direct relation to the usage of jqGrid.